# New iOS team member: no valid signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode, distribution, provisioning

This is getting frustrating. I have two identities, one old, one new, and the latter should be used to deploy iOS apps to the App Store.

I've created the new user, granted him admin access, then I created the app name and provisioning profiles. However, in the Organizer I see that the **Dev** provision works flawlessly, while the **Deploy** profile shows me the dreaded error:

*Valid signing identity not found*.

How can it be?

Well, I see that in the *Certificates* section in the iOS Provisioning Portal, there is only one distribution certificate, the one belonging to my company.

Is there a way to enable the new user to create apps **without** accessing the uberadmin's Xcode?

Thanks & Cheers!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need the key that was used to create the Distribution Certificate for your company.

Remember when you created your developer certificate? Then you went to keychain -> certificate assistant -> Request a certificate from ...

When you did this, your Mac paired your certificate request to a key in your keychain. Once your developer certificate was processed and you downloaded it to your computer, it could be accessed by your computer through that key.

But if you did not create the Distribution Certificate that your company has, you don't have the key on your computer.

**Take a look at your certificates in keychain:**

- Go to 'Certificates' and expand your developer certificate - it will have a little key with your name.
- Now try to expand your distribution certificate - it will *not* have a key, right?

If this is the case, you have two options:

1. Ask the person who created the Distribution Certificate to export it from his keychain. This will create a file that includes both certificate and key.
2. Delete the current Distribution Certificate, and create a new Certificate Signing Request from your computer, which will connect it to a key that you have.

First method require access to "Uberadmins" computer. The second require admin access to your teams Apple account. There is usually no downside in using method 2, because creating a new certificate is necessary from time to time anyway. It will not affect already published apps, just coming releases and updates need to use a the latest certificate.

Once all this is done, you need to create a distribution provisioning profile for App Store and connect to the Distribution Certificate that you are going to use. (if you went with option 1, you might already have done this).

Download the profile to your computer, install it, and then in your app, select to build with this profile for distribution builds.

Comment: Thanks @jake_hetfield, but what if the person that did that pair can't access his computer anymore? I know it's a paradox, but this is what I'm facing...

Comment: Then you have to go with option nr 2 =) It is not a big deal to delete the current certificate (especially not if no one has the key - then it is useless). Just log in with admin access in provisioning portal, delete the dist certificate and follow the instructions that Apple provides on how to create a new one.

Comment: Now I see... I must be sure that the old key isn't available anywhere else, I suppose. Or, if possible, revoke the certificate. Thanks!

Comment: You will have to revoke the old certificate in order to create a new because there can only be one at the time, so no need to worry about the key to the old one... it will not work for the new one...

Comment: @jake_hetfield  Are you sure?  I currently have two distribution certificates listed in the Dev center (on accident).  Kinda freaked me out when it happened.

Comment: I think they changed it since this answer was written. In the new portal, it is possible to add several production certificates it seems.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation:

> A team’s distribution certificate allows a developer to build an app for distribution. If your team wants to use another Mac to create a distribution build, you need to transfer a copy of the distribution certificate as described in, “Safeguarding and Transferring Your Signing and Provisioning Assets” in Tools Workflow Guide for iOS. (from [Managing a Distribution Certificate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH26-SW1))

So, in order to have multiple users able to create & submit App Store builds, you must share a private key between them.

Create a new private key for the team, and then send that private key to everyone who needs it. Follow the instructions under [Generating a Certificate Signing Request with Keychain Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate/ManaginganiOSDistributionCertificate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH26-SW1).

See also: [Any concern to share private key for distribution certificate among different group under a team account in itune provisioning portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305616/any-concern-to-share-private-key-for-distribution-certificate-among-different-gr)